# Round corners of plane wing

Tags: modeling

I want to round the edges of my wing, so it will fit the blueprint. I have tried the Bevel tool, but it does not work in this situation.

[image]

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In edit mode, select only the central vertex and enable proportional editing, sphere falloff, adjust the effect with central mouse wheel and grab (in my example along the X axis).

[image]